# How to use the 'Total Row' style option in Word using Python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am using python along with python-docx with pandas to copy a dataframe into Microsoft Word.

I have successfully managed to copy the data over into a table and apply a style contained within the Word file, but what I *cannot* figure out is how to apply the **Total Row** style option to the final row in the table so that it applies the styles used for totals rows (see screenshot from Word below).

I have tried looking through table styles and latent styles contained in python-docx but can't identify any way of picking the Total Row option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since found out that the current version of the module doesn't support modifying these style options. I have requested the functionality be added in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

OP probably doesn't need answer anymore but I did found work around for this issue.

My issue was that I needed my first column to be in bold while having rest in normal font. It is possible to directly access each paragraph in each cell and set it manually to bold during creation.

This example makes first column bold and leaving rest of the table normal:

```py
row_cells = table.add_row().cells
# Some fake data
row_cells[0].text = 'Heading Row 1'
row_cells[1].text = 'Data 1 Row 1'
row_cells[2].text = 'Data 2 Row 1'
# ...
# This gets Heading Row 1 paragraph and sets it to bold
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.bold = True
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that